# Problems with Solve when constraining solutions to a range

Tags: equation-solving, conditional

I have the following code

```
{e1, e2, e3} = 
{Sin[rot + 2 Pi (# - 1)/3], -Cos[rot + 2 Pi (# - 1)/3]} & /@ {1, 2, 3};
{c1, c2, c3} = 
  1 - 3 (Sin[theta] Cos[phi - 2 Pi (# - 1)/3 - rot])^2 & /@ {1, 2,3};
fq = Total[#[[1]] Exp[I q.#[[2]]] & /@ {{c1, e1}, {c2, e2}, {c3, e3}}];
{theta, phi} = {Pi/2, Pi/2};
rot = 0;
q = {qx, qy};
fqReal = Total[#[[1]] Cos[ q.#[[2]]] & /@ {{c1, e1}, {c2, e2}, {c3,e3}}]
fqImag = Total[#[[1]] Sin[ q.#[[2]]] & /@ {{c1, e1}, {c2, e2}, {c3,e3}}]
{qx, qy} /. 
 Solve[fqReal == 0 && fqImag == 0(*&&-Pi<=qx<=Pi&&-Pi<=qy<=Pi*), {qx, qy}]
```

When I leave the commented-out condition within Solve it works out the solution and gives me the answer in the form of a list of ConditionalExpressions. However when I ask it to also include that condition `-Pi<=qx<=Pi&&-Pi<=qy<=Pi` I get the error warning "Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve." From the physics, I feel quite confident that there is mathematically a solution within this range, so why am I getting the error warning and how do I fix this problem?

Perhaps alternatively, a solution would be to take the ConditionalExpressions and somehow filter them using the condition `-Pi<=qx<=Pi&&-Pi<=qy<=Pi`, however I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Not every equation can be solved with Solve. In this case: try NSolve, to solve the eqn. numerically

Comment: That's what I figured but unfortunately that doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with arbitary `rot`, mentioned in a comment by the OP, is that the equations contain terms like

```
(1 - 3 Cos[π/6 + rot]^2) Cos[qx Cos[π/6 + rot] + qy Sin[π/6 + rot]]
```

That `rot` appears inside `Cos` simply as well as inside `Sin` and `Cos` which are themselves inside a `Cos`, *and* that there are several such terms, makes this a difficult equation to solve symbolically.

But we can differentiate the equations with respect to `rot` and use the solutions when `rot = 0` as initial conditions.  The equations can them be integrated to give numerical approximations to the solutions.  I didn't know what range `rot` might have so I picked `{rot, -π, π}` initially.  `NDSolve` emits a message indicating that it should have been `±0.178`.  *All* of the IVPs have this same stopping point, which must be more than a coincidence and might be deducible from the ODE (if someone is curious).  Note: `Solve` can call `Reduce`, as in [Dr. Wolfgang Hintze's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/16361/dr-wolfgang-hintze) answer, with the option `Method -> Reduce`.

```
{e1, e2, e3} = {Sin[rot + 2 Pi (# - 1)/3], -Cos[rot + 2 Pi (# - 1)/3]} & /@ {1, 2, 3};
{c1, c2, c3} = 1 - 3 (Sin[theta] Cos[phi - 2 Pi (# - 1)/3 - rot])^2 & /@ {1, 2, 3};
fq = Total[#[[1]] Exp[I q.#[[2]]] & /@ {{c1, e1}, {c2, e2}, {c3, e3}}];
{theta, phi} = {Pi/2, Pi/2};
q = {qx, qy};
fqReal = Total[#[[1]] Cos[q.#[[2]]] & /@ {{c1, e1}, {c2, e2}, {c3, e3}}];
fqImag = Total[#[[1]] Sin[q.#[[2]]] & /@ {{c1, e1}, {c2, e2}, {c3, e3}}];
Block[{rot = 0},
  ics = Solve[
    fqReal == 0 && fqImag == 0 && -Pi <= qx <= Pi && -Pi <= qy <= Pi, {qx, qy},
    Reals, Method -> Reduce]
  ];

eqns = Equal @@@ 
   First@Solve[{D[{fqReal, fqImag} /. {f : qx | qy :> f[rot]}, 
        rot] == {0, 0}}, {qx'[rot], qy'[rot]}];
sols = First @ NDSolve[
      {eqns, Through[{qx, qy}[0]] == ({qx, qy} /. #)},
      {qx, qy},
      {rot, -Pi, Pi}] & /@ ics;
```

> NDSolve::ndsz: At rot == -0.178075, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>
>   NDSolve::ndsz: At rot == 0.1780752220309632`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>
>   ...

Some solutions go off to infinity at the singularity near `±0.178`, so I scaled down the domain of `rot` a bit to get a well-proportioned plot.

```
ParametricPlot[{qx[rot], qy[rot]} /. sols // Evaluate, 
  Evaluate@Flatten[{rot, 0.995 (qy["Domain"] /. sols[[1]])}], 
  PlotRange -> All] /. 
 Line[p_] :> {Arrowheads[Table[0.025, {4}]], Arrow[p]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It appears that the set of possible positions `{qx, qy}` might be described as a single curve and its mirror image.  The computed solutions break up the curves where the derivative of `{qx, qy}` with respect to `rot` reverses direction.

Comment: Amazing. This is very helpful, and in-fact I do need to plot a parametric plot exactly as you have. I am still astounded that there are people with such expertise on this site, willing to solve (in such helpful detail) stranger's problems. Thank you! Maybe I can actually deliver a useful result to my supervisor for once =S

Comment: ps there are values of 'rot' for which the equations really do *mathematically* have no solution, which is probably the reason for the singularities you found. There is a simple condition to eliminate these cases which I forgot to include in this post.

Comment: @Michael E2: very interesting idea, that with the differential equation. I have pursued a different path considering the zeroes of fq2a = Abs[fq]^2=fqReal^2+fqImag^2. Introducing polar coordinates qx = t Cos[a], qy = t Sin[a] I then made several Plot3D's for given t, to see the pattern zeroes, and employed Minimize f2qa with respect to rot and a for given t. I found that t>~1.35 is necessary for fq2a=0, in approximate agreement with your graph. I have not seen your critical value of rot=0.174. As Minimize Returns just a rather arbitrary Point (rot,a), the ListPlot is not a nice curve.

Comment: @Michael E2 continued:  I shall edit my solution to show this in more detail. But I think you have already come very close to the final results. Also, from your graph we deduce that introducing polar coordinates for qx, qy might be not the best idea.

Comment: @Michael E2: It can be shown easily using MMA that fqReal(rot+-Pi) = fqReal(rot) and fqImag(rot+-Pi) = - fqImag(rot). Hence your chioce of the region -Pi<rot<Pi is fully justified.

Comment: @Michael E2: I think the minimal value for t is = 2 ArcCos[2/5]/Sqrt[3] ~= 1.338620640527958` (= solution of fq2a(t) = 0 for a=0, rot=0).

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I will be interested to see your update when it is complete. I don't have time right now to look more deeply into the problem.

Comment: @Tom You're welcome. I'm working on a differential equations course, and I'm afraid I've gotten to where I first think, how can I use `NDSolve` here? :) Cheers

Comment: @Michael E2: I also didn't have much time. But now see my EDIT #1. It seems that we have again found a "tasty bone to gnaw on". EDIT #2 in preparation.

Answer (score 3):

Use Reduce.

In fact, with your definitions of `fqReal` and `fqImag`, the command

```
red = Reduce[
  fqReal == 0 && 
   fqImag == 0 && -Pi <= qx <= Pi && -Pi <= qy <= Pi, {qx, qy}]
```

gives

$\left(\text{qx}==-\frac{4 \text{ArcTan}\left[\sqrt{\frac{3}{7}}\right]}{\sqrt{3}}\&\&\text{qy}==0\right)\left\|\left(\text{qx}==\frac{4 \text{ArcTan}\left[\sqrt{\frac{3}{7}}\right]}{\sqrt{3}}\&\&\text{qy}==0\right)\right\|\left(\text{qx}==-\frac{4 \text{ArcTan}\left[\sqrt{\frac{7}{3}}\right]}{\sqrt{3}}\&\&\left(\text{qy}==-\frac{2 \pi }{3}\|\text{qy}==\frac{2 \pi }{3}\right)\right)\|\left(\text{qx}==\frac{4 \text{ArcTan}\left[\sqrt{\frac{7}{3}}\right]}{\sqrt{3}}\&\&\left(\text{qy}==\frac{2 \pi }{3}\|\text{qy}==-\frac{2 \pi }{3}\right)\right)$

or, numerically,

```
red//N
```

$(\text{qx}==-1.33862\&\&\text{qy}==0.)\|(\text{qx}==1.33862\&\&\text{qy}==0.)\|(\text{qx}==-2.28898\&\&(\text{qy}==-2.0944\|\text{qy}==2.0944))\|(\text{qx}==2.28898\&\&(\text{qy}==2.0944\|\text{qy}==-2.0944))$

Best regards,
Wolfgang

**EDIT #1, 08.01.2015**

Eqivalently to the OP we shall consider the roots of the function

fq2 = fqReal^2 + fqImag^2 // Simplify

$\left(\left(1-3 \text{Cos}\left[\frac{1}{6} (\pi -6 \text{rot})\right]^2\right) \text{Cos}\left[\text{qx} \text{Cos}\left[\frac{1}{6} (\pi -6 \text{rot})\right]-\text{qy} \text{Sin}\left[\frac{1}{6} (\pi -6 \text{rot})\right]\right]+\left(1-3 \text{Cos}\left[\frac{\pi }{6}+\text{rot}\right]^2\right) \text{Cos}\left[\text{qx} \text{Cos}\left[\frac{\pi }{6}+\text{rot}\right]+\text{qy} \text{Sin}\left[\frac{\pi }{6}+\text{rot}\right]\right]+\text{Cos}[\text{qy} \text{Cos}[\text{rot}]-\text{qx} \text{Sin}[\text{rot}]] \left(1-3 \text{Sin}[\text{rot}]^2\right)\right)^2+\left(\left(-1+3 \text{Cos}\left[\frac{1}{6} (\pi -6 \text{rot})\right]^2\right) \text{Sin}\left[\text{qx} \text{Cos}\left[\frac{1}{6} (\pi -6 \text{rot})\right]-\text{qy} \text{Sin}\left[\frac{1}{6} (\pi -6 \text{rot})\right]\right]+\left(-1+3 \text{Sin}[\text{rot}]^2\right) \text{Sin}[\text{qy} \text{Cos}[\text{rot}]-\text{qx} \text{Sin}[\text{rot}]]+\left(1-3 \text{Cos}\left[\frac{\pi }{6}+\text{rot}\right]^2\right) \text{Sin}\left[\text{qx} \text{Cos}\left[\frac{\pi }{6}+\text{rot}\right]+\text{qy} \text{Sin}\left[\frac{\pi }{6}+\text{rot}\right]\right]\right)^2$

in the region `g = {-\[Pi]<qx<\[Pi],-\[Pi]<qy<\[Pi]}.`

First we look for symmetry relations which will allow us to reduce

(1) the region `g` to `g1 = {0 < qx < \[Pi], 0 < qy < \[Pi]}`
(2) the number of essentially different roots to 2
(3) the range of the parameter rot to `0 <rot < \[Pi]/6`

As can be easily shown with Mathematica the following expressions are identical to 
`fq2[rot, qx, qy]`

```
fq2[rot \[PlusMinus] \[Pi], qx, qy]
fq2[\[Pi] - rot, - qx, qy]
fq2[\[Pi] - rot, qx, - qy]
fq2[-rot, - qx, qy]
fq2[-rot, qx, - qy]
fq2[rot, - qx, -qy]
fq2[\[Pi]/3 - rot, qx, - qy]
fq2[\[Pi]/3 - rot, - qx, qy]
```

As shown before, the roots for rot = 0 in g1 are

```
z1 = {u, 0};
z2 = {v, 2 \[Pi]/3};
```

where

```
{u, v} = {(4 ArcTan[Sqrt[3/7]])/Sqrt[3], (
   4 ArcTan[Sqrt[7/3]])/Sqrt[3]};
% // N

(* Out[15]= {1.33862, 2.28898} *)
```

In order to study the position of the roots as a function of rot we first get an overview by plotting `fq2`.

It turns our that `ContourPlot` is well suited (`Plot3D` would also work).
Some threshold `eps` was introduced to allow for a tolerance for when an expression is considered to be zero.

Here are the roots for `rot = 0` in the complete region `g`:

```
eps = 0.05;
d = \[Pi];
ContourPlot[{eps == (fq2 /. rot -> 0)}, {qx, -d, d}, {qy, -d, d}, 
 AxesLabel -> {qx, qy}, Axes -> True, PlotLabel -> rr, PlotPoints -> 50]
(* 150108_plot_roots_1.jpg*)
```

[image]

Now for rot = [Pi]/30 in the complete region g:

```
eps = 0.05;
d = \[Pi];
rr = \[Pi]/30;
ContourPlot[{eps == (fq2 /. rot -> rr)}, {qx, -d, d}, {qy, -d, d}, 
 AxesLabel -> {qx, qy}, Axes -> True, 
 PlotLabel -> "Root positions for rot = Pi/30", PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

We see that the two roots `z1` and `z2` start to move towards each other. Also we can see that, by symmetry, is it sufficient to study the first quadrant (`g1`).
The next diagram, for `rot = \[Pi]/18 ~= 0.174533`, show the merging of `z1` and `z2` at a point we call `z3`.

```
eps = 0.05;
d = \[Pi];
rr = \[Pi]/18;
ContourPlot[{eps == (fq2 /. rot -> rr)}, {qx, -d, d}, {qy, -d, d}, 
 AxesLabel -> {qx, qy}, Axes -> True, 
 PlotLabel -> "Root positions for rot = Pi/18", PlotPoints -> 50]
(* 150108_plot _roots _ 3.jpg*)
```

[image]

Increasing rot beyond `~\[Pi]/18`, there is no root left. This is the effect which Michael E2 observed with a completely different method from ours below.

Now we calculate numerically the positions `z1` and `z2` as a function of rot.
Our method uses Minimize[] in order to "catch" the roots.

We start "naively" with a restriction to `g1`:

```
q0 = Table[{rr, 
    Minimize[{fq2 /. rot -> rr, 0 <= qx < \[Pi], -0.1 <= qy < \[Pi]}, {qx, 
      qy}]}, {rr, 0, \[Pi]/6, 0.001}];
q0p = Select[q0, #[[2, 1]] < 10^-6 &];
q0xy = {qx, qy} /. (#[[2, 2]] & /@ q0p);
```

ListPlot-ing already give the general picture, the "root curve" `qy = yq[qx],` although we don't see which root is in which position of the curve

```
ListPlot[{q0xy}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2.5}, {0, 2.5}}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Root curve, joined picture", AxesLabel -> {"qx", "qy"}]
(* 150108_plot_roots_curve_1.jpg *)
```

[image]

The selection of a specific root (z1 or z2) is now done by restricting the region for Minimize.

For z1
(in two parts for improving accuracy)

```
q00 = Table[{rr, 
    Minimize[{fq2 /. rot -> rr, 1.3 <= qx < 1.5, -0.1 <= qy < 1.}, {qx, 
      qy}]}, {rr, 0, 0.1, 0.001}];
q00p = Select[q00, #[[2, 1]] < 10^-6 &];
q00xy = {qx, qy} /. (#[[2, 2]] & /@ q00p);
q1 = Table[{rr, 
    Minimize[{fq2 /. rot -> rr, 0 < qx < 1.6, 0 <= qy < \[Pi]}, {qx, 
      qy}]}, {rr, 0, \[Pi]/16, 0.001}];
q1p = Select[q1, #[[2, 1]] < 10^-6 &];
q1xy = {qx, qy} /. (#[[2, 2]] & /@ q1p);
```

For z2

```
q2 = Table[{rr, 
    Minimize[{fq2 /. rot -> rr, 1.6 < qx < \[Pi], 0 < qy < \[Pi]}, {qx, 
      qy}]}, {rr, 0, \[Pi]/16, 0.001}];
q2p = Select[q2, #[[2, 1]] < 10^-6 &];
q2xy = {qx, qy} /. (#[[2, 2]] & /@ q2p);
```

Before showing the complete root curve in one plot, we provide a fit to the curve

Mathematica has difficulties with `Fit` or `FindFit` in this case. Therefore I did it "by eye and ruler".
With the ruler I found that `qx = w ~= 2.5` is a good center position for a circle for small `qy`.
Hence the equation for qy should look like

```
qy = Sqrt[u^2 - qx^2 - 2 w (u - qx)] /. w -> 2.5
```

Calculating the correcponding table qc and comparing it with the numerical curve, I found agreement after applying a factor 1.84 to the square root.

```
qc = Table[{qx, 1.84 Sqrt[u^2 - qx^2 - 2 w (u - qx)] /. w -> 2.5}, {qx, 
     u + 0.01, v, 0.01}] // Chop;
```

Here ist the complete plot

```
ListPlot[{qc, q00xy, q0xy, q1xy, q2xy}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2.5}, {0, 2.5}}, 
(* detailes suppressed *)  AxesLabel -> {"qx", "qy"}]
(* 150108_plot_roots_curve_02.jpg *)
```

[image]

This curve is to be completed by reflexions about qx- and qy-axes, independently.
The curve is in good agreement with the curve of Michael E2, 
but I believe that the upper part of his curve (beyond the point of inflexion) is spurious and probably due to accuracy deficiencies in NDSolve.

In the next EDIT (#2) I shall present

(i) parametric representation of the components

```
{qx[rot],qy[rot]}
```

(ii) approximate analytic expression for these

Best regards,
Wolfgang

**EDIT #2, 10.08.15**

Approximate analytical treatment.

Close to `rot = 0` we can derive the approximate dependence of `{qx,qy}` on `rot` analytically.

The idea is to develop the equation (letting rot -> r, for simplicity)

```
0 == fq2(r,qx(r),qy(r))
```

in a powerseries aout `r = 0`. As the equation must hold identically, all coefficients of the development must vanish. These conditions are then used to determine the parameters of `{qx[r], qy[r]}`

Let's do it for the two roots `z1` and `z2` separately

*For `z1` (lower root)*

we set, with two parameters a and b:

```
qx = u + a r^2
qy = b r
```

Skipping the details of the calculation we obtain finally

```
qx1[r_] = (4 ArcTan[Sqrt[3/7]])/Sqrt[3] + 
   2/525 r^2 (342 Sqrt[7] - 175 Sqrt[3] ArcTan[Sqrt[3/7]]);
% // N

(* Out[45]= 1.33862 + 2.77773 r^2 *)

qy1[r_] = 2/15 r (9 Sqrt[7] + 10 Sqrt[3] ArcTan[Sqrt[3/7]]);
% // N

(* Out[44]= 4.51352 r *)
```

Eliminating `r` we find the equation between `qx` and `qy`

```
qx1[qy_] = (4 ArcTan[Sqrt[3/7]])/Sqrt[3] + (
   3 qy^2 (342 Sqrt[7] - 175 Sqrt[3] ArcTan[Sqrt[3/7]]))/(
   14 (9 Sqrt[7] + 10 Sqrt[3] ArcTan[Sqrt[3/7]])^2);
% // N

(* Out[48]= 1.33862 + 0.136351 qy^2 *)
```

*For `z2` (upper root)*

we set, with two parameters `a1` and `b1`:

```
qx = v - a1 r
qy = h - b1 r
```

here

```
h = 2 Pi/3
```

Skipping the details of the calculation we obtain finally

```
qx2[r_] = -((2 \[Pi] r)/3) + (4 ArcTan[Sqrt[7/3]])/Sqrt[3] ;
%// N

(* Out[50]= 2.28898 - 2.0944 r *)

qy2[r_] = (2 \[Pi])/3 - 1/30 r (36 Sqrt[7] - 40 Sqrt[3] ArcTan[Sqrt[7/3]]);
%// N

(* Out[51]= 2.0944 - 0.885923 r *)
```

Eliminitating `r` we find

```
qy2[qx_] = (2 \[Pi])/
   3 - ((9 Sqrt[7] - 10 Sqrt[3] ArcTan[Sqrt[7/3]]) (-3 qx + 
      4 Sqrt[3] ArcTan[Sqrt[7/3]]))/(15 \[Pi]);
% // N

(* Out[54]= 2.0944 - 0.140999 (6.86693 - 3. qx) *)
```

*For z3 (where z1 and z2 merge for some r ~= Pi/18)*

Unfortunately, I have not yet found the approach for this case, which seems to be the most interesting.

Regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: This solves my problem, thank you. Although I still have one remaining problem. If I set 'rot' to anything other than 0 I get the error 'Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.'

Comment: @Michael E2: I have now completed EDIT #1 (numerical treatment with Minimize) and EDIT #2 (approximate analytical treatment close to rot = 0). Please check when you find the time. I have not yet found the approximate solution close to z3 (where z1 and z2 merge) for rot = r3 (~= Pi/18 ?).

Comment: Wow, big edit! Thank you, there looks like a lot of interesting content that I will digest. It seems you've found the inversion symmetry and three-fold rotational symmetry of the system which is encouraging. Purely for interest, perhaps I should share that this Mathematica problem relates to finding the 'Dirac points' of 'graphene-like metamaterial' under arbitrary rotations. This work follows on from this paper currently under review: http://arxiv-web3.library.cornell.edu/abs/1411.7796